# Rails with Authlogic, how to remove a default validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, authlogic

I am building an Rails App with Authlogic. But I don't want to force the user to fill in the e-mail, or even username!
Therefore, I believe i want a methods to skip those validations.. But I don't just want to bypass all other validations.

Is there a method for that in Authlogic, or do I need to hack in the gem?

The reason is that I'm using OpenID by authlogic-oid pluguin, and all I know about this is rbates: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic

I get the error primarily from Google (since it don't provide nickname or email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing validations seems to be [a fairly arduous task](http://casperfabricius.com/site/2008/12/06/removing-rails-validations-with-metaprogramming/). You'll need to identify this user somehow in the context of the site, right? Giving them neither a nickname nor an e-mail address to do this with seems not to be an option.

Maybe you should generate a nickname in the `before_validation` method, based off of the data Google provides, if possible. If Google offers no such helpful data (I haven't worked with its OpenID protocol), randomize or use user ID. (Hello, **No-Name 1391**!)

Comment: Awesome answer, worked great! I also added a status field to require additional info later!
Ruby openid is very unpredictable

Answer (score 3):

`acts_as_authentic :validate_email_field => false`